# Can Apple TV estimate what time I will finish viewing the current show?

Tags: appletv, time

The Apple TV shows a progress bar indicating how far along in a program I am. That bar shows the number of hours-minutes in total.

Apple TV is also aware of the current time-of-day, given updates over its internet connection.

Is there any way to have Apple TV estimate the time-of-day when I will complete the viewing of the current show?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Yes.

When you tap the touch surface of the remote in the [4th & 5th generation Apple TV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_TV#4th_and_5th_generation), the progress bar appears as you described, with total length of that program along with an indication of how far along you are.

[image]

**Tap that touch surface a second time.** The labels on the progress bar to show the current time-of-day and the estimated time of completion. Just what you asked for.

[image]

Comment: Covered in Apple's instructions? Source? Or is this un-documented behaviour?

Comment: I can't find anything in the documentation about this. I think it was added in a recent tvOS 11 point update, because I don't recall my Apple TV doing this until recently.